# Is there a potential data leak when redirecting from http to https?

Tags: heroku, redirect, https, http-redirect, fastify

I have the following code in my Fastify server hosted on Heroku:

```js
this.server.addHook('preHandler', async(req, reply) => {
  const isHttps = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https';
  if (isHttps) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    method,
    url
  } = req;

  if (method && ['GET', 'HEAD'].includes(method)) {
    const host = req.headers.host || req.hostname;
    reply.redirect(301, `https://${host}${url}`);
  }
});
```

The idea is to prevent access to the server through `HTTP` and force redirection to `HTTPS` at the application-level, since [it is not possible otherwise on Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls).

My question is: if the first request to the server via `HTTP` (before the redirection happens) contains sensitive information such as a username/password, wouldn't that still be "dangerous" or compromising somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably mis-configured something on Heroku.

Heroku domains (.herokuapp.com) are [by default HTTPS enabled](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint). The same page has a guide for custom domain SSL setup guide. Since you are talking about (username + password), I am going to assume this is a website. All you need to do is setup CORS with fastify-cors. Your website should ALWAYS be served over HTTPS.

Also you should not use the logic above. Fastify isn't meant to be used as a proxy server. The docs strongly suggest using a front-facing proxy server like nginx. With Heroku you don't need all these. It already handles this for you.

In the future you could also use Cloudflare as a "proxy server" outside Heroku.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the person calling the API (exposed by Fastify) may choose to send the data over HTTP at first.

Comment: Yes, data will be exposed.